# When to store longitude and data in a spatial enabled DBMS and when to store as Float?

Tags: postgresql, gps, gis, postgis, database

I have a bunch of latitude and longitude data from my GPS running watch, and I want to store that in a DB, I've been reading about GIS but I don't know what does a spatial enabled DBMS like PostGIS allows me to do that simply storing the data as Float wouldn't.

Comment: It probably will support matching within a specified distance, order by distance, etc. Also, here is a shameless plug for my personal favourite, MongoDB, which is a general DB but supports spatial indexes: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Comment: PostGIS enables the ability to do geospatial queries that you may not be able to as a float.  PostGIS can be used to answer the question 'with elevation and curvature of the earth included, how far did I run between these two points?'.  Answer to your question will depend on your intent, if you just want to store and plot...float probably works fine...if you want a fuller set of geospatial functions, PostGIS is where you'll want to go.  An 'unplug' MondoDB horribly failed our internal geospatial stress tests, died in about 3 hours of simulated production use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot will depend on what you want to do with that data.  Something like PostGIS will make working with that data a lot easier, depending of course on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres is optimized for geo-search.